# How do I display local stored data in form while displaying form

Tags: angular

I have a registration form with some data which I am storing in local storage and want some field of registration forms like first name and last name to be displayed when my second form gets loaded. this data should come from local storage. the code snap is of the second form.

```
  onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.dataModel);`enter code here`
  this.submitted = true;
  this.registerService.firstdata(this.dataModel)
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log('Success!', data))

}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userData = localStorage.getItem('user_data');
  }


 <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName"
              [(ngModel)]="dataModel.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+">
            </div>

 <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName"
              [(ngModel)]="dataModel.lastName #lastName="ngModel" required pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+">
            </div>
```

Comment: Please provide others details

Comment: If I've understood right: you want the fields of your form to be pre-compiled with that you get from localStorage?

Comment: Jacopo Sciampi : yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

If your local storage contain firstname and lastname then Update your dataModel in ngOninit() as below

```
ngOnInit() {
this.userData = localStorage.getItem('user_data');

// update first name and last name from local storage
this.dataModel.firstname =  this.userData.firstname; // get data here from local storage
this.dataModel.lastname =  this.userData.lastname; // get data here from local storage

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are already fetching data from local storage in `ngOnInit` you just need to initialize `dataModel` fields.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.userData = localStorage.getItem('user_data');

  this.dataModel.firstName = userData.firstName;  // <-- Assuming field name in localstorage as userData.firstName
  this.dataModel.lastName = userData.lastName;    // <-- Assuming field name in localstorage as userData.lastName 
}
```